# What is the best way to insert an array of variable length of data into a sql database?

Tags: javascript, sql, react-native, sqlite

So I have a form of variable size and users can add any amount of fields they like.

an example of form values is like this:

```
{variableSizedArray: [
    {name: car1Name, age: car1Age}, 
    {name: car2Name, age: car2Age}, 
    {name: car3Name, age: car3Age},
    ...
]}
```

How would I go about inserting each value into my SQL database?

Things I tried:

1. Executing a SQL statement for each value:

```
     variableSizedArray.forEach((item) => {
         db.exec("INSERT INTO cars (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)", [item.name, item.age]); 
     })
```

But this will cause many calls to the database which I believe is bad practice?.

2. Creating a custom string:

```
     variableSizedArray.forEach((item) => {
         insertString += `(${item.name}, ${item.age}),`;
     }
     db.exec(`INSERT INTO cards (name, age) VALUES ${insertString}`);
```

this is the solution I am using right now but it's getting quite complicated since I have much more variables in my project and I need to create a different "custom string" builder for every new "operation" I make.

Are those the only 2 options and is my understanding of their drawbacks correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try https://github.com/reconka/Cordova-sqlite-storage-bulkinsert/blob/9e72c4ca44dd56df38233dbda42fcc6de80363d4/android/assets/www/js/index.js